# force re-render of custom textfield view

Tags: ember.js

How to force to re-render a custom textfield view?

I create a:

```
App.Select2View = Ember.TextField.extend({didInsertElement:function() {//plugin called here}});
```

It's included in a template form and when the form is open and I select another/different item, this custom textfield view (based on select 2) doesn't re-render but stays the same.

I have nested routes/resources. Company under companies. When I select a company I have readonly info and edit button that if clicked calls action on the Company controller to "isEditing" state, in this state a form is open. If I change the state to false it goes back into read only model (viewing the company info).

It's fine if I set it back to read only mode first, and then open another item and the select2 is rendered with this companies data.

But if it's in the isEditing state, with form open and I navigate to another company item all form input fields change according to model (such as name will change because it's binded to the name key value of the company model), but the select2 stays the same as previous.

I'm not sure how to re-render this in Ember.

This is defined as partial in template under the main company template view:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="company/_edit">
    <p>{{input type="text" value=name}}</p>
    <p>
        {{view "select2"
        prompt="Search for companies" 
        resource="results" 
        displayKey="text" 
        onSelect="addCompany"
        onDeSelect="removeCompany"
        }}
    </p>
</script>
```

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Can you create a failing bin? It would people to answer your question. emberjs.jsbin.com

Comment: sure, but this will have to be put on hold as I have run into others issues which maybe part of the problem as well. if I clear that up I will post up a jsbin. basically my problem is when I click on another item in "edit" state, the form renders for that item with the data populated, but the select2 doesn't rerender. What I did temporarily to solve it is to add a "beforeModel" method on the CompanyRoute, and do: this.controllerFor('company').send('cancel'), which cancels the edit state: this.set('isEditing', true); for the cancel in the actions hash on the CompanyController.

Comment: and then when I click on the edit button, it will render the form view with the select2 rendered as well.

Comment: the problem is that when it's in that "edit" state, and I click on another item, the select2 will remain the same as for the first item that as clicked.

Comment: also works with "willTransition" event I put on the CompanyRoute with: this.controller.send('cancel');, but again this takes it out of editing state, I want to keep it in edit state and navigate to any item with the select2 render properly for that item. weird.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Ember and my answer might not be apt, but based on my experiments the problem is that Ember caches as much as possible. So it won't re-render the view completely with the select2, only when view is in a certain state previous state followed by next state will it automatically re-render.

The solution atleast for now seems to be to add a "valueChange" method with observer on "value" change on the select2 custom TextField and make the same call as in "didInsertElement" (which executes when the view is rendered):

```
valueChange: function() {
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, 'setupSelect2');
}.observes('value'),
```

Now even if I'm in the "edit" state, it will update this select2 as well, not just the standard form inputs tied specifically to the model. I can now navigate to any item in "edit" state which has form open for each item selected and values change correspondingly in the select2.